# Electrical problems after jumping 2008 chevy silverado

Tags: electrical, battery, chevrolet, silverado

After jumping truck, my stabilitrack light stays on, service brakes light stays on, and my radio does not power off when key is turned off (or when I open door).  Not sure where to start to locate the problem.  Can anyone please lead me in the right directions??  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, disconnect both battery cables and touch them together for a few mins. That will reset all the computers. Then reconnect. If you still have the warning lights, get the trouble codes read. It's possible you fried a few modules. Jump starting can do that sometimes. It's rare, but sometimes the spark creates a surge large enough to damage electronics.

Comment: I would agree with your starting point, but would ensure the OP charges the battery completely before assuming something is wrong. If the battery is low on voltage, it might be enough to start the vehicle, but the electronics might be doing strange things. Seen it several times on different vehicles.